# DVI display not detected on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I've installed ubuntu 17.04 and connected the nvidia gtx1080 to a dvi monitor. Everything was working fine until I added a hdmi connection to a TV (connected to the same gpu).

Now the only display showing something is the TV, the monitor display is not even detected. I ran xrandr and the output were that there's nothing connected to the dvi input.

This is a screenshot that's maybe related to my problem:

[image]

Comment: are your minitor set mirror? it appear that ubuntu can't find a common resolution

Comment: Yes @ravery I remember settings the displays on mirrored mode before this error message. But now  I can't even modify that because the monitor display is not detected, only the TV appears in the display settings.

Comment: does the monitor work without the TV connected? which desktop are you using?

Comment: Without the TV, I'm able to get to the grub boot screen. But, no matter what  option I choose, I can't get to the OS screen. I'm using Unity

Comment: look in ~/.config  for monitors.xml. delete it and restart your computer with the tv disconnected. LightDM should rewrite the file.

Comment: I've already done that, but same problem. I can access the OS console and when I execute the xrandr command the message is "Can't open display"